# Get number of hours as an int since specific date in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, formatting

So, I have an issue that I'm trying to wrap my head around.   Essentially I have a database that shows when computers were last connected to the database.   I am supposed to calculate the uptime of the computers as a percentage (hours connected since first connect / total hours since first connect.)

All I have is a single DateTime field in a mysql database.    At that point I could do a "Select TIME from database where ID="1" order by TIME asc limit 1" to get the oldest date, but how would I get the number of hours since that DateTime object?

The desired output would be something like "95%"   -- which could be 19 / 20 or something.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Having two columns, first connect and last connect, would make this super easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
timestampdiff(HOUR,NOW(),OLDESTTIME) as uphours
```

that would give you difference in hours between two datetime

Answer (score 0):

Convert your [DateTime to a timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), subtract the oldest from the latest and divide the result by 60 and by 60 again:

```
(LatestTime-OldestTime)/60/60
```

Should give you the number of hours between them.